# Symfony2 phpunit cannot find test file

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I try to run additional tests on Form component in symfony2 with phpunit.

If I set the folder in the command line, tests are running correctly :

`phpunit src/Symfony/Component/Form`

but when I add some tests, total count of tests doesn't change.

When I try to run it on the specific class :

`phpunit src/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractLayoutTest`

I get an error message : *"Class 'src/Symfony/Component/Form/Tests/AbstractLayoutTest' could not be found in '/Users/****/Sites/dev/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Tests/AbstractLayoutTest.php'."*

But class name matches file name...

Can someone please give me a clue on what's wrong ?

### EDIT

My bad. It was an abstract class so phpunit does not call it...

Comment: can you try `phpunit -c app src/Symfony/Component/Form`?

Comment: got *"Could not read "app"."*

Comment: Try running from the project root: `./vendor/bin/phpunit -c app .....`
If you have sf2 bin path: `./bin/phpunit -c app...`

Comment: @RenatoMendesFigueiredo see my edit, it's solved. Abstract class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`phpunit` **never** calls **abstract class** methods